# Spark streaming, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/avro/functions$

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-avro

i am trying to read data from kafka stream, that uses avro serialization for value.
I have no problem reading data, and deserializing key that is string, but when i try to deserialise data using from_avro function i get exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/avro/functions$
    at DataFrameExample$.main(DataFrameExample.scala:41)
    at DataFrameExample.main(DataFrameExample.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.functions$
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 12 more
```

Sbt file:

```
name := "test"
organization := "com.databricks"
version := "1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.17"
// Spark Information
val sparkVersion = "3.3.0"
// allows us to include spark packages
resolvers += "bintray-spark-packages" at
  "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"
resolvers += "Typesafe Simple Repository" at
  "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/maven-releases/"
resolvers += "MavenRepository" at
  "https://mvnrepository.com/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % sparkVersion % Provided
)
```

Code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro.functions._
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

object DataFrameExample extends Serializable {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Example")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN");

    val currentDirectory = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath
    println(currentDirectory);

    val df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option(
        "kafka.bootstrap.servers",
        "localhost:9091,localhost:9093,localhost:9094"
      )
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("subscribe", "test-person-activity-partitions-replication-qwe")
      .load()

    val jsonFormatSchema = new String(
      Files.readAllBytes(
        Paths.get("./src/main/resources/avro/person-activity.avsc")
      )
    )

    val df2 = df.select(
      df.col("key").cast("string"),
      from_avro($"value", jsonFormatSchema).as("value")
    )

    df2.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

when running application using spark submit i also provide spark_sql_kafka_0-10, which i cannot provide from sbt since i get some other errors, this is not directly related to this problem, but if someone knows what could be the reason for this feel free to answer to that also.

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0 --class DataFrameExample --master local target/scala-2.12/test_2.12-1.jar
```

Sorry if this is duplicate but i have looked at every answer o so and other places when searching for similar errors. Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#deploying), add the package on command line. Ensure version values are correct.

```
spark-submit --packages "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.3.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0" \
             --class DataFrameExample \
             --master local target/scala-2.12/test_2.12-1.jar
```

Comment: Thank you but can you explain to me why would we need to provide it directly here, when it is provided in build.sbt file, if it is removed from build.sbt it will not be able to run sbt package, so at the moment it is needed in both places

Comment: @NikolaRoncevic tldr: I have no idea how sbt works, so can't really answer. But 1. clearly the problem is class is not found. 2. my ans should (hopefully) solve that. 3. you're already doing the same for kafka, so this is not something too new to your setup.

Comment: Yes it worked, and it was not a problem, i was just curious if you knew a bit more regarding the issue, anyhow, thank you very much and have a good day.

Comment: @NikolaRoncevic curious what worked, this answer or the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75754623/496289 ?

Comment: I forgot to mark your answer as accepted, then marked the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the dependency in your Sbt file, but you are mentioning that it is provided: `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % sparkVersion % Provided`
This means that this dependency is excluded from being on the class path by default. As a result, it isn't included into a fat jar artifact. That's why when you run `spark-submit` command, it doesn't find that dependency.
To solve that you have two options:

- Pass the jar to the `spark-submit` command using the `--packages` option:

  `--packages "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.3.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0"`
- Change the scope of your dependency as compile:
  `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % sparkVersion % Compile`

Comment: @NikolaRoncevic fell under pressure ? curious what answer was clearer :D